# I create the .jar file but I can't use .jar file in my new project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jar

I create a .jar file from my old project and try to use the .jar file in new project its crash application.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.clientapp, PID: 2837
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field abc_text_select_handle_left_mtrl of type I in class Landroidx/appcompat/R$drawable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'androidx.appcompat.R$drawable' appears in /data/app/~~m2UIxY8m41H6F1206VId5A==/com.example.clientapp-uQDl-7yLeT3HZC91kbld4Q==/base.apk)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$1.<init>(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:93)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.preload(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:62)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:342)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:292)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:230)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:586)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.attachBaseContext(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:7939)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3622)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3832)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2247)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:568)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

I have only one layout in my new project the layout name also different from the .jar file and  the both project package name also different i don't know where i mistaked please help.

This is my new project build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.clientapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.clientapp"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation files('libs/BpLibrary.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Comment: your error message is not about a library that is missing, but about a field within a class it used.

Comment: You didn't provide any source code to understand the issue.